# Error in eval in 3 way anova

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to find if Hardness of soil is significantly different with treatment, fertilizer and different layer of soil.

```
summary(aov(Hardness~Depth*Till *Amendment+factor(Block)))
```

I used this but I am getting error

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Hardness' not found

same error with this code

```
TukeyHSD(aov(Hardness~Depth*Till *Amendment+factor(Block)))
```

[image]

Comment: How would R know to look in your `Depthwise.hardness` data if you don't tell it to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to let R know where the source data for the model is:

```
summary(aov(Hardness~Depth*Till *Amendment+factor(Block), data = DEpthwise.hardness))
```